How to change size by pressure on mac trackpad - GIMP
I am using a macbook air running MacOS Montery and I draw and paint with the trackpad - not a stylus. The trackpad is pressure sensitive since it's a macbook air and while messing around with more basic drawing apps I have noticed to I can change the brush thickness in them by pressing harder on the trackpad.
I clicked Pressure Size under dynamics. Honestly I don't know what to do beyond that. Really I have no idea what I'm doing. I clicked 'edit this dynamics' and i can't change anything under mapping matrix.

I don't think you can do that with the trackpad, the setting is meant for use with a stylus.

It is likely GIMP 2.10 can't make use of it - but GIMP 3.0 (you can already use the 2.99 pre-release), likely can - you have to go under edit->preferences->input devices->input controllers and fiddle with the settings there to activate any non-basic input device. (It may even work with GIMP 2.10 - just go there)
